# Hierarchiqual prediction using R

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, text-mining

I'm pretty new in R, and I couldn't find any information about a package who can do the following: supposing that I have a set of data (for instance, different text documents), which can have several classes.

For example, a datum could be a Sport, a Sport with Ball, a Sport without Ball and a Car. I'd like to be able to predict to which category the data belongs, considering that I may not hit that the datum is a Sport with Ball, but I'd be happy if I correctly predict that it's a Sport.

Which package can provide this kind of stuff? Some examples would be useful, if possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am also looking for similar examples - `http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104481/hierarchical-text-classification-in-r` . Did you find some thing on this, can you help