# Hierarchical text classification in R

Tags: r, text-mining

I am working Automatic Email routing. My historical data set has Email Description,Division and Category. There are around 20 division and 150 categories.

I have built one vs. all classifier (RTextTools - SVM) for 20 divisions and trained 20 classifier and when the new email comes in , my container(SVM Models) gives me predicted Division (with good accuracy).

My question is from here( after getting Division, since i have got good accuracy level using one vs. all approach - ) - how would i predict Categories . As there are 150 levels - i cannot do one vs. all - as did for Division.And more than 80% of data the is covered with in 40 Category levels.

Can somebody suggest a way of getting Category level prediction(second level) - or any reference how it can be done in R.

Comment: Can somebody help on this, i am stuck

Comment: Try to see if this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23715803/hierarchical-prediction-using-r